# singledispatchmethod with typing types

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

In Python 3.8 a new decorator for creating polymorphic functions was created, @singledispatchmethod, which redirects Python to the correct implementation of your method depending on the type hints provided.

However, I don't seem to be able to use complex types from the typing modules, please could you tell me what is wrong with my example?

```py
from typing import List
from functools import singledispatchmethod
class test:
    @singledispatchmethod
    def a(self, a):
        return NotImplemented

    @a.register
    def _(self, a : str):
        print(type(a))
    
    # Uncomment to run the example
    # @a.register
    # def _(self, a: List[str]):
    #    print(type(a))

    def b(self, b: List[str]):
        print(type(b))

test().a(["A"])
test().b(["A"])
```

If the comment of the second underscore function is uncommented, the following error occurs with the a function, even tho it doesn't happend with the b one:

```
TypeError: Invalid annotation for 'a'. typing.List[str] is not a class.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like another bug in the definition of `singledispatch`. The `register` method explicitly checks if the annotation for the parameter is an instance of `type`, which is not the case for a type hint.

Comment: @chepner do you know if this is in a bug tracker anywhere, or did OP just find a new stdlib bug?

Comment: Maybe this? https://bugs.python.org/issue34498

Comment: I think that issue covers this. Function annotations have always been allowed to be arbitrary expressions, even if they were virtually always types in practice. PEP-484 started the road towards *requiring* the annotation to be something type-like, but the `typing` module was the first thing to introduce non-type type-like objects. `singledispatch` just doesn't seem to be keeping up with these developments.

Comment: thanks for the references, at least I know there wasn't something I was doing wrong in this case

Answer (score 2):

From the comments, it sounds like there might be [potential changes](https://bugs.python.org/issue34498) to `singledispatchmethod`, but if your are interested in available work-arounds to allow both dispatching and typing to work here are some options:

1. Register the overload with the actual class `list` and then provide more specific type hints for the overload ([see related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68423105/3780389)).
2. Use a project like [`multimethod`](https://github.com/coady/multimethod) which handles more parameterized `typing` types.

#### Option 1: Register with `list` and add more specific overload type hints

```py
from functools import singledispatchmethod
from typing import List, overload


class test:
    @singledispatchmethod
    def overloaded_a(self, a):
        return NotImplemented

    @overloaded_a.register
    def _(self, a: str):
        print(type(a))

    @overloaded_a.register
    def _from_list(self, a: list):
        print(type(a))

    @overload
    def a(self, a: str): ...

    @overload
    def a(self, a: List[str]): ...

    def a(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.overloaded_a(*args, **kwargs)

    def b(self, b: List[str]):
        print(type(b))


test().a(["A"])
test().b(["A"])
test().a("this")
# test().a([34])  # mypy error: List item 0 has incompatible type "int"; expected "str"
# test().b("this")  # mypy error: Argument 1 to "b" of "test" has incompatible type "str"; expected "List[str]"
```

#### Option 2: Use `multimethod`

```py
from typing import List

from multimethod import multimethod as singledispatchmethod


class test:
    @singledispatchmethod
    def a(self, a):
        return NotImplemented

    @a.register
    def _(self, a: str):
        print("str")
        print(type(a))

    @a.register
    def _from_str_list(self, a: List[str]):
        print("str list")
        print(type(a))

    @a.register
    def _from_int_list(self, a: List[int]):
        print("int list")
        print(type(a))

    def b(self, b: List[str]):
        print(type(b))


test().a(["A"])
test().a([3])
test().b(["A"])
# test().b(3) # mypy error: Argument 1 to "b" of "test" has incompatible type "int"; expected "List[str]"
```